# Is there any way to shortcut this method? Hide/Show element on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to ask you guys if I can shortcut this code as I think it can be more less code but I'm learning right now Javascript/Jquery.

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
    function(){
            $(".facebook").click(function () {
                    $("#facebook_prices").show("slow")
                    $("#twitter_prices").hide("slow")
                    $("#youtube_prices").hide("slow");
            });});

    $(document).ready(
    function(){
            $(".twitter").click(function () {
                    $("#twitter_prices").show("slow")
                    $("#facebook_prices").hide("slow")
                    $("#youtube_prices").hide("slow");
            });});

    $(document).ready(
    function(){
            $(".youtube").click(function () {
                    $("#youtube_prices").show("slow")
                    $("#facebook_prices").hide("slow")
                    $("#twitter_prices").hide("slow");
            });});
</script>
```

Comment: Add your HTML too to get the better insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is to only use one document.ready handler. You don't need to repeat it for every operation.

The pattern you're looking to follow here is called 'Don't Repeat Yourself', or DRY. To achieve this you can apply common classes to the elements which trigger events and use the `href` (assuming the trigger is an `a` element) or `data` attributes to store custom metadata to separate the actions performed by each element. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".trigger").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.price').hide('slow');
    $($(this).attr('href')).show("slow")
  });
});
```

```css
.price {display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#facebook_prices" class="trigger">Facebook</a>
<a href="#twitter_prices" class="trigger">Twitter</a>
<a href="#youtube_prices" class="trigger">Youtube</a>

<div class="price" id="facebook_prices">
  Facebook prices...
</div>
<div class="price" id="twitter_prices">
  Twitter prices...
</div>
<div class="price" id="youtube_prices">
  Youtube prices...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I've modified a few things on my code and now it works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use comma ( `,` )  to similar elements to `hide()`

Check below code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".facebook").click(function () {
        $("#facebook_prices").show("slow");
        $("#twitter_prices,#youtube_prices").hide("slow");
    });
    $(".twitter").click(function () {
        $("#twitter_prices").show("slow");
        $("#facebook_prices,#youtube_prices").hide("slow");
    });
    $(".youtube").click(function () {
        $("#youtube_prices").show("slow");
        $("#facebook_prices,#twitter_prices").hide("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: It could be argued this is still needlessly repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below implementation. Removed the repetitive .ready() methods and merged the hide functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideAll(){
        $("#facebook_prices").hide("slow")
        $("#twitter_prices").hide("slow")
        $("#youtube_prices").hide("slow");
    }

    $(document).ready(
    function(){
            $(".facebook").click(function () {
                    hideAll();
                    $("#facebook_prices").show("slow");
            });

            $(".twitter").click(function () {
                    hideAll();
                    $("#twitter_prices").show("slow");
            });

            $(".youtube").click(function () {
                    hideAll();
                    $("#youtube_prices").show("slow");
            });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Your `hideAll()` function shows the `#facebook_prices`. The repeated `click()` handlers are also needlessly repetitive.

Comment: Oh! my bad. Missed it while copying from the question. @RoryMcCrossan thanks :+1 . 
The question did not have an HTML implementation and assuming the HTML isn't my style, so added the repetitive `click()`. I'm open for suggestion if there is a better way.

Comment: Sure, I posted an answer above.